# The issue for using @inlinable init when setting BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION to YES

Tags: swift, xcode, frameworks, inline, xcframework

I have a class with @inlinable init in a framework project.
It compiled OK until I set BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION = YES in my XCode build settings in order to build a XCFramework.

The compiler errors will disappear if I remove @inlinable marks.

Is there any way to keep @inlinable in this scenario? Thanks!

[image]

**Update**

I found this [article](https://swiftrocks.com/understanding-inlinable-in-swift) which kind of tells why the compiler is not happy with @inlinable here

> On the other hand, @inlinable can be a massive problem depending on what you're building. If the implementation of an @inlinable method changes, the modules that import it will not be able to make use of the modifications unless they are recompiled. Normally you would be able to update a framework by simply replacing the binary, but because the implementation of some methods got inlined, the app will keep running the old behavior even if you're linking to the new version. Because of this, apps with the library evolution setting enabled may find themselves unable to play around with @inlinable, as this can break the ABI stability of your framework.